# Get Custom Option Price in order

Tags: price, custom-options

I have custom option in my product i want to show selected custom option with price in order.
i have used below code to get all custom option

```
foreach ($sales_model->getAllItems() as $item) {

     $opts = $item->getProductOptions();


}
```

when print option array it will give array without price.so how can i get option price.

```
[options] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => Tour Date
                [value] => 10/04/2014
                [print_value] => 10/04/2014
                [option_id] => 3433
                [option_type] => date
                [option_value] => 2014-04-10 00:00:00
                [custom_view] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [label] => Adult
                [value] => 4
                [print_value] => 4
                [option_id] => 3434
                [option_type] => drop_down
                [option_value] => 14224
                [custom_view] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [label] => Adult - Cruise + Lunch
                [value] => Yes
                [print_value] => Yes
                [option_id] => 3435
                [option_type] => checkbox
                [option_value] => 14231
                [custom_view] => 
            )
```

any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that sales item contains information about selected option but not about option price.

So to get the price you need first:

- get product object,
- after get custom option collection(which contains all product custom options with prices).
- get product custom option from collection by option id and get its price.

Try this:

```
foreach ($sales_model->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $selectedOpts = $item->getProductOptions();
     $productOpsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getProductOptionsCollection();
     foreach ($selectedOpts as $selectedOpt) {
         $optPrice = $productOpsCollection->getItemById($selectedOpt['option_id'])->getPrice();
     }
}
```

Comment: it gives error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on a non-object `

Comment: Then check what values do you have in `$productOpsCollection` and if option with `$selectedOpt['option_id']` option id exist in collection.

Comment: Now i get price for  Date option only it still doesn't print price for dropdown or checkbox type.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying I got this way:

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
    $finalPrice = 0;
    foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item){
        if ($optionIds = $item->getProduct()->getCustomOption('option_ids')) {
            foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                if ($option = $item->getProduct()->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                    $confItemOption = $item->getProduct()->getCustomOption('option_'.$option->getId());

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setConfigurationItemOption($confItemOption);
                    $finalPrice += $group->getOptionPrice($confItemOption->getValue(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up your template file

**app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**

Find the foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
```

Within that foreach loop, add this code:

```
<?php

        $optionId = $_option['option_id'];
        $product = $_item->getProduct();
        $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
        $itemOption = $_item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
        $price = false;
        foreach ($option->getValues() as $values) {
            if ($values->getId() == $itemOption['value']) {
                $price = $values->price;
            }
        }
        if ($price !== false) {
            echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($price);
        }

?>
```